# IDEA AutoComplete Proper Exception

Tags: intellij-idea, exception, kotlin

I have a function(AFunction) which maybe throws XXException.
I write BFunction like this

```
try{
    AFunction()
}catch(e:){
    // Some Code
}
```

When I write `e:`,how can IDEA complete `XXException` (the Most Proper Exception).
I have tried `ctrl+space` `alt+enter`,they lists many Exceptions.

Thanks!

Comment: The code doesn't look like a Java code. Is it Kotlin? Have you tried [smart completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#smart_completion) action?

Comment: @Andrey I'm sorry.Yes,it's Kotlin. But I think that it is the basic function to all language.....

Comment: @Andrey I have tried smart completion action.It just lists many Exceptions(some of them are unnecessary).

Comment: It smart complete does not work, feel free to file a request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT with the simple complete sample code to reproduce.

Comment: @Andrey Thanks, I will file a request if it's needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin does not have checked exceptions. Because of that, it has no information about exceptions that `AFunction` may throw, and does not filter the completion list for exception classes.

Comment: You may want to highlight that it does have some information (from java methods or from annotations), but as the information is not complete it does not filter based on it.

Comment: I have tried [Throws Annotation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-throws/index.html). But,it fails.